# How to catch React Navigation unhandled route?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a question regarding React Navigation. In my project, I have some event generated navigations and this can penitentially go wrong. What I would like to do is catch an unidentified route with a call back or a try/catch. Is there a way to achivie that?

Use case:

When the navigation encounters an undefined route, a callback is made where this can be handled and the app redirects to a Home Screen or logs the error.

How can this happen?

I have a system where the business side can create interactive components in the app that can redirect the user to screens, I want to make sure that we handle every case.

Comment: why in first place will your app navigate to a unhandled route?

Comment: Can you share your use case?

Comment: @TommyLeong when the source of the route name is outside the application?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?